# How to get predicted labels for more than two classes?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I implemented an image classifier in Keras using the TensorFlow backend. For a dataset with two output classes I checked predicted labels:

```
if  result[0][0] == 1:
    prediction ='adathodai'
else:
    prediction ='thamarathtai'
```

[Full code](https://github.com/kajasumanie/medical-plant-classification). With three classes I get `[[0. 0. 1.]]`. How can I check predicted labels for more than two classes in if else format?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a multi-class classification problem with k labels, you can retrieve the index of the predicted classes by using `model.predict_classes()`. Toy example:

```
import keras
import numpy as np

# Simpel model, 3 output nodes
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(3, input_shape=(10,), activation='softmax'))

# 10 random input data points
x = np.random.rand(10, 10)
model.predict_classes(x)
> array([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

If you have the labels in a list, you can use the predicted classes to get the predicted labels:

```
labels = ['label1', 'label2', 'label3']
[labels[i] for i in model.predict_classes(x)]
> ['label2', 'label2', 'label3', 'label2', 'label3', 'label2', 'label3', 'label2', 'label2', 'label2']
```

Under the hood, `model.predict_classes` return the index of the maximum predicted class probability for each row in the predictions:

```
model.predict_classes(x)
> array([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1])
model.predict(x).argmax(axis=-1) # same thing
> array([1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: i was implemented above lines but i got " only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index' error.

Comment: I think because predicted_class is 2-dimensional. Try reshaping it to be 1d, or just use predicted_class[0][i]

Comment: I updated my answer, the easiest solution is to use `model.predict_classes`.

Comment: i got dimensions error with shape .i really don't understand  can you please explain me a bit. i uploaded  my full code .thank you .

Comment: i didn't get  this line    "x = np.random.rand(10, 10)"

Comment: It generates some random data for my example, 10 data points with 10 features.

Comment: finally understood!! I changed it to 1d  and predict the class. thanks a lot for your help.